# Enabling migrations for project where context in different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm running:

```
enable-migrations -ContextProjectName CC.Data -StartUpProjectName CC.Web -ContextTypeName CC.Data.CcDataContext -ProjectName CC.Plugin.MyPlugin -Force -Verbose
```

This creates the configuration file in `CC.Plugin.MyPlugin.Migrations` called `Configuration.cs` however when it completes it throws this error:

> The migrations configuration type
>   'CC.Plugin.MyPlugin.Migrations.Configuration' was not be found in the
>   assembly 'CC.Plugin.MyPlugin'.

I don't understand how it can't find it as it's just added it there. The congif file looks like this:

```
namespace CC.Plugin.MyPlugin.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CC.Data.CcDataContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(CC.Data.CcDataContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

which looks fine.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: This appears to be an issue with linking references from projects within the same solution. As soon as I removed these references from the solution linking and instead did it via Browse and pointed to the DLL's, it started working.

Comment: That's strange... Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution? Which project is selected as "default project" in the package manager console?

Comment: I've cleaned and re-built a number of time, tried changing the `internal sealed` to `public` (you never know :) ) and no luck. The default project is set to my `CC.Plugin.MyPlugin` project.

Comment: I've been playing with this and it appears that when working on the project directly (not as part of the other group of projects under the solution) I've got it to work. I find this odd but I'll report back when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: *This has NOT fixed the issue. Whilst it let me add the initial migrations, it appears that it's broken again when I try and run update-database (Even though I did have it working).*

After much trial and error I've found the cause of this to be needing to update my ASP.NET MVC references in all projects within my solution. Once I did this, it worked like a charm.

Added to this, migrating some other plugins also caused issues which again through trial and error it appears I needed to add Webgrease reference via Nuget and update ANTLR to the latest version.

Another gotcha on this: My plugins are part of the main solution. In order to get some to update, I had to open on it's own. Save the solution file. Enable Nuget auto restore. Clean Build, try and enable migrations, let it fail. Undo all my changes in source control. Load it via the main solution again and then add migration at which point it complained about references that it couldn't find. Once I added these (or removed and re-added in some cases) it worked. Very strange but it might be useful for someone else.